# Get shipping address county in Magento 2 observer

Tags: magento, magento2

Hi I have a custom module . I want to get shipping country inside

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
```

Please let me know how can i get this  this ?

I have seen this code for postcode , but i am not sure his is working or not

```
  $postCode = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()-getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
```

I need **shipping address country name** in public function execute. Please help .

Answer (score 0):

declare a public variable and intialize the variable like below ,then you will be able to use it in your execute method

```
class Example {
 
public $_checkOutSession;

public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $checkOUtSession)
{
$this->_checkOutSession = $checkOutSession;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  $postCode = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which observer do you want to get it. Can you provide a more specific scenario?

In which checkout session currently has a quote. You can use the above solution from Reggie.

Or else you need to initialize quote/order to get it.